# Ruby: Not able to compare values correctly in JSON file

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, mapping

This is the code to fetch JSON file with diastolic values > 100

```
    def self.hypertension_observation_high(bundle) 
      entries = bundle.entry.select {|entry| entry.resource.is_a?(FHIR::Observation)}
      observations = entries.map {|entry| entry.resource}
      hypertension_observation_statuses = observations.select {|observation| observation&.component&.at(0)&.code&.text == 'Diastolic Blood Pressure'}
      hypertension_observation_statuses.map do |observation| 
        x = observation&.component&.at(0)&.valueQuantity&.value.to_i
        y = observation&.component&.at(0)&.code&.text
        puts (observation&.component&.at(0)&.code&.text)
        puts y.class
        puts (observation&.component&.at(0)&.valueQuantity&.value)
        puts x.class
        puts (x > 100)
        puts '..........'
      end
      hypertension_observation_statuses.any? {|observation| observation&.component&.at(0)&.valueQuantity&.value.to_i > 100 }
    end
```

This is my console; And it is showing all the values and types correctly:

```
..........
Diastolic Blood Pressure
String
79
Integer
false
..........
Diastolic Blood Pressure
String
105
Integer
true
..........
Diastolic Blood Pressure
String
98
Integer
false
..........
Diastolic Blood Pressure
String
116
Integer
true
..........
Diastolic Blood Pressure
String
110
Integer
true
..........
Diastolic Blood Pressure
String
118
Integer
true
..........
Diastolic Blood Pressure
String
108
Integer
true
..........
Diastolic Blood Pressure
String
99
Integer
false
..........
Diastolic Blood Pressure
String
99
Integer
false
..........
Diastolic Blood Pressure
String
115
Integer
true
..........
```

This is my JSON file:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/1gdm6bdu2p1r84i/Aaratrika954_Butt355_59939a08-96e1-68d0-76c8-ec52b4b5308a.json?dl=0

But, I am NOT getting the correct JSON file with the required values in the output. I am even getting the values with <100

Comment: The file you posted includes personal identification data like names, birthdays, and social security numbers. Is this test data or actual data of your patients or customers? If the latter then I suggest deleting the file immediately and informing the customers about the data breach.

Comment: Its a synthetic test data created randomly. No issue of privacy

Comment: It's unclear what `bundle` and `FHIR::Observation` are from this code. Can you update your post to include more so others can replicate?